# Why even when using a sorted observable list, my combobox is not sorted?

Tags: sorting, javafx, arraylist, combobox

I am trying to display a sorted list of items in a combobox in javafx.

In my controller, my list of items is declared list this :

```
private final ObservableList<Profile> profiles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private final SortedList<Profile> sortedProfiles = new SortedList<>(profiles);
```

My combobox is initialized like so :

```
profiles.setItems(controller.getSortedProfiles());
```

Then, I have a method in my controller to be able to add items :

```
profiles.add(new Profile(profileName));
```

The combobox is updated, but not sorted. Why ? I thought that using a sortedlist wrapper would keep the combobox sorted ?

Sample code :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class Demo extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final ObservableList<Item> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        items.add(new Item(1));
        items.add(new Item(100));
        items.add(new Item(10));

        final SortedList<Item> itemSortedList = new SortedList<>(items);

        final BorderPane view = new BorderPane();

        final ComboBox<Item> profiles = new ComboBox<>();
        final Button add = new Button("add random");
        add.setOnAction(event -> items.add(new Item(new Random().nextInt(5000))));

        profiles.setItems(itemSortedList);

        view.setTop(profiles);
        view.setBottom(add);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(view, 400, 400);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static final class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
        private Integer name;

        public Item(final int name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Int : " + name;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(final Item o) {
            return name.compareTo(o.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sample code added

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `ComboBox` is properly sorted. Remember that `String` is compared _lexicographically_.

Comment: I have changed the demo code, now using Integer instead of string, nothing changed. I even added some data to have something at the start at the app, purposely not sorted.

Comment: Ah, I see why I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. I'll write an answer.

Comment: I am using Java 1.8.0u144 on OSX 10.15.1 with JavaFX 8.0.141-b14 (found by using System.out.println(com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo.getRuntimeVersion());

Comment: Never mind, fabian beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never set the `comparator` property of the sorted list. [The javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html#comparatorProperty) contains the following statement about the `comparator` property:

> The comparator that denotes the order of this SortedList. Null for unordered SortedList.

I.e. without specifying a comparator the list simply keeps the order of the original list. Just specify the comparator to fix the issue:

```
final SortedList<Item> itemSortedList = new SortedList<>(items, Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Alternatively if you add the appropriate getter you could easily create a `Comparator` sorting by a given property (provided this property is comparable):

```
final SortedList<Item> itemSortedList = new SortedList<>(items, Comparator.comparing(Item::getName));
```

Comment: For natural ordering one can also use [`ObservableList#sorted()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#sorted()).

Comment: Thanks ! That's was indeed the solution. The question is now, why a constructor exists that permit to not set a comparator ! I mean, the sortedlist is meant to be used to sort a list, but we can use it without sorting ....

Comment: There may be a case where you want to do a binding making an initialisation unnecessary. Also it may be usefull in fxml, since `null` may not be the simplest value to produce there...